# What is included in the Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition ISO downloaded from Microsoft Download Center?

Tags: visual-studio

What specifically does the ISO version include? Does it include Windows 10 tools and SDKs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-vs and https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads. Windows 10 SDK is included.